# Phaser framework user account

Tags: input, phaser-framework, account

I have built a prototype for a simple game.

This game is used by parents and children.

The next stage of the app, is the ability to create a simple user account for the child, managed by the paren.

Steps:

1. The parent would create an account and input the child's name.
2. The account would keep simple data about the game and save the data to be retrieved,
   the next time that the game is played.

Is this kind of thing possible in Phaser ?

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage should do the job. Create an object and pass it to localStorage like

```
localStorage.setItem("user", JSON.stringify(user));
```

to save it and then retrieve it using

```
var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user")).toString();
```